# Invoke-WebRequest - Property shows as having value but when accessed in certain way it is null

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following command to pull values from html input fields on a web management interface on a simple linux printing device.

```
$get = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("http://" + $station + ":8080/cgi-bin/admin?page=pedi.sh&hash=" + $hash) -Method "GET
```

One of the input fields is a check box, I need to be able to check if this is checked or not. In this case the checkbox is named "Protocol" and it is checked.

```
$get.ParsedHtml.getElementsByName("Protocol") | Select checked
```

> checked
>   True

If I try to get the value with the following command it returns nothing.

```
($get.ParsedHtml.getElementsByName("Protocol")).checked
```

But if I do this I get the value...

```
($get.ParsedHtml.getElementsByName("Protocol") | Select checked).checked
```

I'm wondering why I'm seeing this behavior, is this normal?

I'm running Windows 8 RTM, PowerShell 3.0.  If you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: Do you get a count of more than 1? $get.ParsedHtml.getElementsByName("Protocol") | measure

Comment: Results:

$get.ParsedHtml.getElementsByName("Protocol") | Measure-Object


Count    : 1
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your issue. To get the value of the checked property (or any other property), I had to force the return object to be an array, like so:

```
@($get.ParsedHtml.getElementsByName("Protocol"))[0].checked
```

Or, since Powershell 3.0's new property enumeration feature:

```
@($get.ParsedHtml.getElementsByName("Protocol")).checked
```

So it seems to only supply the value when the value is requested through enumerating the collection returned from getElementsByName. Maybe someone can chime in and explain this behavior. I am guessing it has something to do with the fact that this is using com objects?